# Java Swing Login Form

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm trying to create a login form using Java Swing. But I want the layout to look tighter, but still responsive.

**The structure of my project**

```
Project/
└── src
    ├── GUI
    │   ├── Control.java
    │   ├── Main.java
    │   └── pages
    │       ├── LoginPanel.java
    └── Helper
        └── Helpers.java
```

**Edit**

After trying out the answer posted, I got:

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pmts.png)

The components in the `form` panel are not behaving as I would expect

And my code:

LoginPanel

```java
package GUI.pages;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int PADDING = 30;
    // Some labels, button, groups and fields
    private static JLabel usernameLabel;
    private static JTextField usernameInputField;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JPasswordField passwordInputField;
    private static JButton submit;
    private static JLabel title = Helpers.generateTitle();


    public LoginPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(400, 400);

        JPanel titleContainer = new JPanel();
        titleContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, PADDING, PADDING));
        titleContainer.add(title);

        // the username row
        usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
        usernameInputField = new JTextField(50);

        // The password row
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        passwordInputField = new JPasswordField(150);

        JPanel form = new JPanel();
        form.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,0);
        form.add(usernameLabel, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,0);
        form.add(passwordLabel, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.1;
        c.ipadx = 200;

        form.add(usernameInputField, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 0.001;
        c.weightx = 0.001;
        c.ipadx = 200;

        form.add(passwordInputField, c);

        // The message label, the text depends on the query's result.
        message = new JLabel();

        // Configuring the submit button
        submit = new JButton("Sign in");
        submit.addActionListener(new LoginActionListener());
        submit.setActionCommand("login");

        // Configuring the redirecting button
        registerRedirect.setActionCommand("registerRedirect");
        registerRedirect.addActionListener(new Router());


        JPanel submitContainer = new JPanel();
        submitContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, PADDING, PADDING));
        submitContainer.add(submit);

        form.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, passwordInputField.getHeight()));

        // adding everything to the layout

        add(titleContainer, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(form);
        add(submitContainer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    }
}
```

Main

```java
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import GUI.pages.LoginPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 750;
    public final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 550;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        JPanel login_panel = new LoginPanel();
        add(login_panel);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This is how I want it to look like(updated):

```
REM(the title)        
________________________________
           __________________
Username: [__________________]
           __________________
Password: [__________________]
                      
                   [Submit button]
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'm not clear if the <kbd>submit</kbd> button is right aligned or centered, but..

- BLUE area: `BorderLayout`.
- RED area: `GridBagLayout` - with labels right aligned, and text fields left aligned. In the `CENTER` of the border layout.
- GREEN areas: `FlowLayout` with `PAGE_START` left aligned & `PAGE_END` either center aligned or right aligned (as per need).

Comment: *"The button is right aligned"* Uh-huh .. so, you're sorted?

Comment: Have you looked at the [API documentation for flow layout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)? The documentation should be the first place you look. The constructors for flow layout would be a good place to start.

Comment: Show your attempt in the form on a [mre] as an [edit] to the question. It sounds as though the code did not use the constraints for the `PAGE_START` and `PAGE_END` when adding components.

Comment: *"I have updated it."* Go back and read the MRE document again. also read he page on the [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). A longer page talking about the same thing, but with more detail. What is posted above is neither R of the first nor SC of the second.

Comment: If that code seen in the edit is copy/pasted into a new project in your IDE, does it compile cleanly without change (including an automatic adding of import statements by the IDE)? Does it run? The code needs imports and a main method to put it on-screen. One of the ideas of an MRE / SSCCE is to make it easy to test. People who offer free help here have limited time and only an 'academic interest' in solving problems. If there are a lot of people asking questions, we focus effort on the ones who make it easy for us to help!

Comment: `// never mind this` Well if it hadn't caused a compilation error, I would not have (minded it). Before you waste more of your time (& more importantly, mine), please paste your code into a new .. oh why bother? You obviously ignored that advice in my last comment. All the best with it.

Comment: I edited it again, I tested it out, the frame indeed shows up, sorry for the time I wasted posting non-sense code.

Comment: Sorry if I disobeyed the guideline, I'm completely new to StackOverflow, but I do want to join a community where I can learn from other programmers. So once again, thank you for your time and effort spent on this post! But please, can you just help me please?@Andrew Thompson